# Wordpress fancybox plugin not working

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, fancybox

The `fancybox` plugin has been driving me insane for some reason the past 2 hours. I have got it to work on other sites in the past however it is refusing to work now.

So I have this bit of code calling the post the images are in:

```
<ul>
    <?php query_posts('cat=4'); ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"></a>
            <?php $content = get_the_content();
            print $content; ?></li>
    <?php endwhile;?>
</ul>
```

In `wordpress` I have a post (in cat 4) with 2 images in `<ul> <li>`, in the CSS they are set `display: inline;`

Can't see what's wrong?

Comment: Did you check the error console? What are the other js plugins that you're using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that you have `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` before the `</body>` tag and `<?php wp_head(); ?>` in your theme `<head>` section.